# What is the name of type T && in C++?

Tags: c++

If I have a function `f(T *)` I would describe that as `f takes a pointer to T`.

`f(T &)` would be something like  `f takes a reference to T`.

How do I pronounce `f(T &&)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the context. When `T` is known type then `T&&` is an *rvalue reference*. When `T` is a template parameter then `T&&` is a *universal reference*.

Comment: The C++1z Standard drafts use the term *forwarding reference* instead of *universal reference*. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4164.pdf

Answer (score 2):

That would be an "r-value reference"